# How to show this limit is zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is it true that the following limit is zero as $n$ goes to infinity for all positive integers $k$? If so, how to prove it? 
$$n\left[(n-1)^{-\frac{1}{k}}-n^{-\frac{1}{k}}\right]$$

Comment: What have you tried? (Given the presence of the $\infty-\infty$ indeterminate form, I'd use the conjugate trick.)

Comment: sorry which conjugate trick?

Comment: Can you differentiate? The mean value theorem yields the result fairly quickly.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I know how to do it. Wish I could select your comment as the correct answer :D

Comment: @ larrybr: Sorry, it doesn't work after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$
\frac{x^k-y^k}{x-y}=x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}y+x^{k-3}y^2+\cdots+x^2y^{k-3}+xy^{k-2}+y^{k-1}
$$
if we set $x=(n-1)^{-\frac1k}$ and $y=n^{-\frac1k}$, we get that your expression is equal to
$$
\begin{align}
&\small n\frac{\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n}{(n-1)^{\frac{1-k}k}+(n-1)^{\frac{2-k}k}n^{-\frac1k}+(n-1)^{\frac{3-k}k}n^{-\frac2k}+\cdots+(n-1)^{-\frac2k}n^{\frac{3-k}k}+(n-1)^{-\frac1k}n^{\frac{2-k}k}+n^{\frac{1-k}k}}\\[9pt]
&\le\frac{\frac1{n-1}}{kn^{\frac{1-k}k}}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{n^{-\frac1k}}k\frac n{n-1}\\[12pt]
&\to0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: but when k=1, the expression goes to zero..

Comment: Ah, I read the exponent as $\frac1k$ instead of $-\frac1k$. Fixing...

Comment: could u explain how you expand it plz?

Comment: I have prefaced my answer with an expansion I had assumed.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the mean value theorem: For any fixed power $p<0,$

$$x[(x+1)^p-x^p] = x[p(c_x)^{p-1}\cdot 1]$$

for some $c_x \in (x,x+1).$ In absolute value the above is $\le x|p|x^{p-1}.$ Now use the fact that $p<0$ to find the limit as $x\to \infty.$

Answer (score 2):

Write $$(n-1)^{-1/k}=n^{-1/k}\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{-1/k}$$and expand the term in parentheses as

$$\left(1-\frac1n \right)^{-1/k}=1+\frac{1}{kn}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Thus

$$n\left((n-1)^{-1/k}-n^{-1/k}\right)=\frac1k n^{-1/k}+O\left(n^{-1-1/k}\right)\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,n\to \infty$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(n-1)^{-\frac{1}{k}}-n^{-\frac{1}{k}}=n^{-\frac{1}{k}}\left\lbrack\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-\frac{1}{k}}-1\right\rbrack$$

Now $\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-\frac{1}{k}}-1=\frac{1}{nk}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Multiplying this by $n^{1-\frac{1}{k}}$, you get $\frac{n^{-\frac{1}{k}}}{k}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{k}}}\right)$